# asp.net page stops working for no reason (gridview/sqlexpress search)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sql-server-express

I have an asp.net page with a gridview and a couple of input text boxes and a search button.
Once I put something on both text boxes and press search, I get a result list (gridview) from a MS SQLExpress 2008 database.

Everything runs great BUT for some unknown reason the search stops working every now and then.
I type values on the two text boxes and press Search.
Instead of getting a result like always, the text on the text boxes dissapear, on the bottom says status "Done" but in fact is not displaying anything.

it gives no errors at all...it just runs...but doesn't display any data.

I have tried used several other Pc's as clients, same problem.
I have closed and restarted IE/Firefox but does't fix it.
Turning off-on the web server's pc fixes it sometimes, but of course I don't want to be doing that every 30 minutes

Any comments/ideas are appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you supply some code to show the core bits of what your app is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's giving you a redirect to GET. My guess is you're set to use Forms Authentication, and it's timing out. Try increasing the timeout, or removing authentication.

You could use Fiddler to verify that it's redirecting you.

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is my first time creating an asp.net web application so I am still a beginner...
When you say "remove authentication" what's that exactly ?

Sorry for being a newbbie.